# How does a snowblower perform on exposed aggregate concrete?

Tags: concrete, driveway

I wish to replace my asphalt driveway with concrete. I am hoping to do something a little more visually interesting than just a slab, though. I like the look of exposed aggregate, but I am concerned about snow removal. Will my snowblower constantly catch on the rocks? Will it leave snow between the stones that builds up to ice? Does anyone have experience snow blowing exposed aggregate?

Comment: You may find that the concrete surface is much less prone to self-thawing in sunlight than black asphalt. Exposed aggregate is also going to basically encourage ice remaining between the raised aggregate bumps. You may live to regret this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most snow blowers have adjustable skid shoes that look something like this:

[image: Skid Shoes]
<sub>(source: [jackssmallengines.com](http://www.jackssmallengines.com/graphics/DIY/Images/adjust-skid-shoes-step3.jpg))</sub>

On smooth hard surfaces, you can typically adjust these to the minimum height so the snow blower "scrapes" the surface.  If you have a rough surface then you can adjust these so the blade rides a bit higher and does not catch any of the rough surface.

Comment: I suspect that on exposed aggregate concrete the skid shoes won't even need to be adjusted, since the surface will still be basically flat. They're probably more important for truly uneven surfaces like a gravel or stone driveway. But this is a a good tip for anyone with a snowblower.

Comment: Mine doesn't have that, but it's on its last legs. The next one will. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have any problem on your aggregate. I've used snow blowers on some very rough ground including hard dirt and loose dirt and did not even pick up any dirt with the snow you should have no problem whatsoever.